# SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '»'

Tags: python, sql-server, csv

I was exporting CSV data file into a SQL Server database using Python scripts.

```py
with open ('07132021.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns = next(reader) 
    query = 'insert into database_table({0}) values ({1})'
    query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    for data in reader:
        cursor.execute(query,data)
    cursor.commit()
```

I got the following error:

> '42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '»'. (102)

The traceback pointed to this line of code

```py
cursor.execute(query,data)
```

Comment: What does the already formatted ```query``` variable look like so we can check that ?

Comment: Using string concatenation or formatting to create SQL queries is a *very* bad idea that exposes you to SQL injection attacks, not just problems like this one. What if one of the values was `'; drop table users; --` ?  In this case it seems that one of the `columns` values contains typographical double quotes. I suspect it was copied from an HTML page or a Word document

Comment: You've no doubt encountered the Unicode BOM, `U+FEFF`, that appears at the beginning of UTF-8 encoded files as `0xEF 0xBB 0BF` - which in code page 1252 is the character sequence `î»¿`. Have you tried reading the Python documentation, [Reading and Writing Unicode Data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data)?